# Scala package object - val declaration

Tags: scala

In Scala 2.9.1, when I declare the package object for "com.sample.website"

```
com.sample

package object website {
  val (CONST_1, CONST_2, CONST_3) = (1, 2, 3)
}
```

The compiler throws 3 errors like

```
not found: value CONST_1
```

Am I doing something wrong or am I simply not allowed to use pattern matching value declaration in package objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this linke [How to pattern match into an uppercase variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636972/how-to-pattern-match-into-an-uppercase-variable), pattern match doesn't work with uppercase variables.

You need to convert it lower case variables or do it seperate.

Answer (score 2):

Pattern matching only binds to lower case variables, in all contexts.

```
val (A,B) = (1,2)     // Checks that A==1 and B==2
val (a,b) = (1,2)     // Sets a=1, b=2
```