# Error: Not found: Value S (Scala)

Tags: arrays, scala, naming-conventions, declaration

```
val Array(k,s) = readLine.split(" ").map(_.toInt)
```

This code works fine. But not this:

```
val Array(k,S) = readLine.split(" ").map(_.toInt)
```

Capitalizing "s" here gives me an error: `error: not found: value S`

What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are creating the `k` and `s` identifiers with `val Array(k,s) = ...`, you are using pattern matching to define them.

From the [Scala Specifications](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) (*1.1* Identifiers):

> The rules for pattern matching further distinguish between variable
>   identifiers, which start with a lower case letter, and constant
>   identifiers, which do not.

That is, when you say `val Array(k,S) = ...`, you're actually matching `S` against a constant. Since you have no `S` defined, Scala reports `error: not found: value S`.

---

Note that Scala will throw a `MatchError` if the constant is defined but it still cannot find a match :

```
scala> val S = 3
S: Int = 3

scala> val Array(k, S) = Array(1, 3)
k: Int = 1

scala> val Array(k, S) = Array(1, 4)
scala.MatchError: [I@813ab53 (of class [I)
  ... 33 elided
```

Comment: Is there a better way to do a double (or more)-variable assignment from a single line of space-delimited integers compared to the one in my post?

Comment: @user4992519 : I'm assuming you still want `S` to be uppercase ?

Comment: I don't believe there is, at least not using pattern matching (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636972/how-to-pattern-match-into-an-uppercase-variable)). Why do you need `S` to be uppercase ? The [Scala Style Guide](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html) say that values/variables should start by a lowercase letter.

Comment: Just for consistency's sake with other external programs I am cross-referencing with. Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

When using extractors, symbols that begin with a lower case character will be interpreted as a variable to hold an extracted value. On the other hand, symbols that begin with an upper case character are used to refer to variables/values declared in an outer scope.

Another example:

```
val X = 2

something match {
  case (X, y) => // matches if `something` is a pair whose first member is 2, and assigns the second member to `y`
  case (x, y) => // matches if `something` is a pair, and extracts both `x` and `y`   
}
```