# Scala - Cannot resolve symbol - Looping through map

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am doing programming in scala for looping through map.

Below is my code which works fine.

```
     val names = Map("fname" -> "Robert", "lname" -> "Goren")

     for((k,v) <- names ) println(s"Key: $k, Value : $v")
```

When looping through the map, if I give (K,V) instead of (k,v), the program is not compiling. It gives cannot resolve symbol error.

Below is my for loop -

```
     for((K,V) <- names ) println(s"Key: $K, Value : $V")
```

I am executing this program in IntelliJ IDEA 15 scala worksheet.

Can anyone please explain the reason for this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't compile for the same reason this code doesn't compile:

```
val (A,B) = (1,2)
// error: not found: value A
// error: not found: value B
```

but this *does* compile:

```
val (a,b) = (1,2)
// a: Int = 1
// b: Int = 2
```

> Constant names should be in upper camel case. That is, if the member
> is final, immutable and it belongs to a package object or an object,
> it may be considered a constant
>
> **Method, Value and variable names should be in lower camel case**

Source: http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html

Comment: some more explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636972/how-to-pattern-match-into-an-uppercase-variable